# Intercepting all user touches for an iOS app without overriding sendEvent

Tags: ios, touch

I'd like to intercept all touch events occurring in an app without interfering with the app functionality (eg after doing something with the touch event, pass it on to the rightful receiver). Is there any way it can be done other than

- overriding `sendEvent` in the `UIApplication` class by subclassing it
- using method swizzling on UIView to get my own `touchesBegan` etc. functions being called
- putting an `UIView` on top of all other views in the app, catching all touches and sending them through

so that it could be used as a reliable external framework functionality?

**EDIT:**

Adding a gesture recognizer to the application window would work - is there any other way (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: Do you want to block the events from being forwarded sometimes, or you just want to know the events happened?

Comment: I just want to know the events happened, e.g. log them.

Comment: Have you tried adding a gesture recogniser to the app window (being its delegate so it doesn't block other recognisers)?

Comment: Indeed, that one I forgot to mention - that would work, too. Any more possible ways?

Comment: why not use "touchesBegan" and its supportive functions https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Because that would require either a view on top of all views where the touchesBegan resides or a base class that overrides the touchesBegan function - which would change the code, and that is not possible from an external framework.